# content should be adjusted in every screen resolution without writing media queries

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I have been asked to design a webpage for fixed resolution 1024x980. This will not be HTML5/RWD/mobile.This will be a web application on 1024 x 768 resolution for desktop/laptops. It should not break while accessing from mobile/tablets. It should reduce and fit-in small screens. Is there any way of achieving this without writing media queries.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: have you tried using **margin:0 auto;** to your page? this will center your page on any screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

*Use Parent width:100% height:100% & specify the width , height of other elements in % .*